# How to rebuilt Azure Web App's deployment slot feature with plain IIS?

Tags: iis, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently running my web application on Azure Web Apps and I'm using deployment slots to publish to a staging area and then switching production with staging after the staging area looks fine.

However, I'm unsure if I can stay with Azure Wep Apps - primarily because Azure Web Apps defy some monitoring and diagnostics tools that I probably need to investigate weird application behavior.

That's why I'm wondering what the best way to re-build the deployment slot feature is.

One important requirement is that the application pools don't get recycled during the switch.

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 2):

We don't offer an equivalent for deployment slots in IIS. You can look at installing the Azure Stack to run Web Apps on-prem and have more control over the OS and you can look at the Diagnostics as a Service functionality of Web Apps to see if it helps with your diagnostics needs.
Thanks!
Nir (App Service team)

Comment: Can you provide any links? I found the site "Azure Stack in your Data Center" but it's not targeted to technical people so there's no substance and it seems intimidating.

Comment: Echoing @John. Please provide links! I can find no download bits for Azure Stack, just white papers and high level docs.